# I have 15 UIButton in my iPhone project, after clicking on button one image is pop up and all images are different for different button?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uibutton, uitouch

I have 15 UIButton in my iPhone project, after clicking on button one image is pop up and all images are different for different buttons, how could I achieve this by using touch?

How should I call proper image for particular button?

I dont want to take 15 UIButtons and 15 UIImageView .

Comment: You already have 15 `UIButton`s right now. Please edit the question. I think you don't want to create 15 method, right? Specify clearly what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You could have all 15 buttons hooked to one single "`IBAction`" method.

When the method is called, the parameter that is sent (e.g. "`(id) sender`") is the object that sent the message.

If you assign different tags to each button, you'll know which button called the action method and then you could have a different image appear for each different button.

All you need here is one "`IBAction`" method and one "`IBOutlet`" for a single image view.  You will still need to have some kind of logic to load 15 different images into that single image view, though.

Comment: Yes Michael, you are 100% correct.But I need UITouch or UITapGesture solution for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do: 
This is called after any button is clicked:

```
-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(UIButton *)sender {

   if(sender.tag == 0){
    NSLog(@"Button one");
} else if(sender.tag == 1){
    NSLog(@"Button two"); ... // like wise do it for 15 buttons
}

}
```

All you have to do is assigne tag to the button when you create it.
I think you must be running a for loop 15 times to create those buttons, 
so:

```
for(i=0;i<15;i++){
 //create button..
 button.tag = i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a background image of the view with all the 15 button information, which is divided to 15 locations to detect the touches.
Get the touch location (co-ordinates) and based on the particular location that is pre defined, update the image in the popup UIImageView accordingly.

this might help to get the location of the touch in the view.

[UIView touch location coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370997/uiview-touch-location-coordinates)

Answer (score 0):

You could use IBOutletCollections, this requires that you hook up the 15 UIButtons in a Xib.
The following code assumes you have a collection of N-buttons.  For a given gesture, it will iterate over the buttons in the collection and determine if the location of the touch is within a buttons frame.

Edit: IBOutletCollections are available in iOS 4 and up.

Assuming you have the following as properties:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton)    NSArray  *collection_buttons;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
```

And the following synthesizes:

```
@synthesize collection_buttons = _collection_buttons, imageView = _imageView;
```

Then you could use the following code on gesture call back.

```
-(IBAction) tapGestureOnButton:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) gesture {
    CGPoint point = [gesture locationInView:self.view_buttonContainer];

    for( int index = 0; index < self.collection_buttons.count; index++ ) {
        if( CGRectContainsPoint(((UIButton *)[_collection_buttons objectAtIndex:index]).frame, point)) {
            //Button at index has been pressed
            [imageView setImage:[button backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal]];               

            break;
        }
    }

}
```